How to resolve the 'loca' table is mandatory issue when rendering PDF with PDFBox in Java?
I'm using PDFBox to render PDFs to images in Java, but I encounter an error related to the NotoColorEmoji font. Here's the exception stack trace:

java.io.IOException: 'loca' table is mandatory
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:225)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:165)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:79)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:27)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:110)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:73)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.(PDCIDFontType2.java:112)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.(PDCIDFontType2.java:65)

Additionally, I see warnings regarding fallback fonts and unprocessed cmap tables in the NotoColorEmoji font:

2024-12-03 12:07:24.869  WARN 100617 --- [main] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font : Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Symbol
2024-12-03 12:07:25.179  WARN 100617 --- [Finalizer] org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument : Warning: You did not close a PDF Document
2024-12-03 12:07:25.492  WARN 100617 --- [main] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 : Could not read embedded OTF for font NotoColorEmoji

In an attempt to solve the issue, I tried loading the NotoColorEmoji font manually as shown in the code below:
PDDocument PDFdocument = new PDDocument();
PDFdocument = PDDocument.load(inputStream);

PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(PDFdocument);
List<DocumentPage> documentPages = new ArrayList<>();

// To avoid noticoloremoji font error
if (PDFdocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm() != null &&
    PDFdocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getDefaultResources() != null) {

    PDResources resources = PDFdocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getDefaultResources();
    
    boolean fontPresent = false;
    for (COSName fontName : resources.getFontNames()) {
        if (fontName.getName().equals("NotoColorEmoji")) {
            fontPresent = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (fontPresent) {
        File fontFile = new File("NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf");
        PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(PDFdocument, fontFile);
        resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("F1"), font);
    }
}

for (int page = 0; page < PDFdocument.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
    float height = PDFdocument.getPages().get(page).getMediaBox().getHeight();
    float width = PDFdocument.getPages().get(page).getMediaBox().getWidth();

    BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
}


However, the issue persists.I'm using Java 1.8 with the following dependencies in my pom.xml for PDFBox:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.32</version>
</dependency>


The emoji font file is likely not a real ttf file, try another one. Also install the Symbol.ttf font on your machines. And use identical pdfbox and font box versions.
